# mongodb-enterprise release 3.2.11 async insertMany fails with "not authorized on imvisiondb to execute command"

Tags: java, mongodb

Any idea why when running **insertMany asynch** command using 3.4.0 java client drivers (including the asynch driver), and the server itself is release 3.2.11 the result is failed with :

Message: **Command failed with error 13: 'not authorized on imvisiondb to execute command** { insert: "CadlStoredObjects", ordered: true, documents: 2 }' on server 10.0.0.186:27017. The full response is { "ok" : 0.0, "errmsg" : "not authorized on imvisiondb to execute command { insert: \"CadlStoredObjects\",
 ordered: true, documents: 2 }", "code" : 13 }

The mongo db server logs are :

2016-12-12T15:43:06.723+0200 I ACCESS   [conn538] Successfully authenticated as principal user on imvisiondb

2016-12-12T15:43:06.755+0200 I ACCESS   [conn537] Successfully authenticated as principal user on imvisiondb

2016-12-12T15:47:29.608+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.0.0.186:58314 #539 (51 connections now open)

2016-12-12T15:47:29.634+0200 I ACCESS   [conn539] Unauthorized: not authorized on imvisiondb to execute command { insert: "CadlStoredObjects", ordered: true, documents: 4 }

2016-12-12T15:47:37.618+0200 I ACCESS   [conn539] Unauthorized: not authorized on imvisiondb to execute command { insert: "CadlStoredObjects", ordered: true, documents: ........

2016-12-12T15:47:39.594+0200 I ACCESS   [conn539] Unauthorized: not authorized on imvisiondb to execute command { insert: "CadlStoredObjects", ordered: true, documents: 2 }

Downgrading the server to mongodb-enterprise 3.2.9 solved the problem.

How come the server release affects the asynch behavior ?